# How to add the values of the children object and push it to the corresponding parent

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have a json structure as below

> [{      "name": "minpur",       "children": [{
>             "name": "ppp1",
>             "children": [{
>                 "name": "feeder",
>                 "children": [{
>                     "name": "rmu16",
>                     "children": [{
>                         "name": "invt16",
>                         "children": [{
>                             "aname": "inv 01",
>                             "value": 300
>                         }, {
>                             "aname": "inv 03",
>                             "value": 500
>                         }]
>                     }]
>                 }]
>             }]      }]   }]

i want to add the value of children object and push to the corresponding parent
like below

> [{    "name": "minpur",   "value": 800,   "children": [{      "name": "ppp1",
>         "value": 800,       "children": [{          "name": "feeder",           "value": 800,
>             "children": [{
>                 "name": "rmu16",
>                 "value": 800,
>                 "children": [{
>                     "name": "invt16",
>                     "value": 800,
>                     "children": [{
>                         "aname": "inv 01",
>                         "value": 300
>                     }, {
>                         "aname": "inv 03",
>                         "value": 500
>                     }]
>                 }]          }]      }]  }] }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a recursive function that iterates the children, and adds the value according to their children, etc...

**Note:** the `value` property in the example appears after the `children` property.

```js
const fn = arr => arr.map(o => {
  if(!o.children) return o
  
  const children = fn(o.children)
  const value = (o.value || 0) + children.reduce((r, { value }) => r + value, 0)
  
  return {
    ...o,
    value,
    children
  }
})

const data = [{"name":"minpur","children":[{"name":"ppp1","children":[{"name":"feeder","children":[{"name":"rmu16","children":[{"name":"invt16","children":[{"aname":"inv 01","value":300},{"aname":"inv 03","value":500}]}]}]}]}]}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```